# Exporting Vector Graphics from HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, vector, export

I'm curious if that's possible?  I'm interested in building a vector drawing app within HTML5 that has the ability to save as vector, and not just JPG/PNG/BMP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/).

It draws stuff on Canvas, and has SVG import/export.
It handles 'objects', common SVG shapes and paths. The full SVG standard (fonts, for example) isn't supported, but maybe you only need to use a subset of it.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible.  After the drawing operations are complete all you're left with on the `canvas` are a bunch of pixels.  You'd have to retain all the drawing options and then use them to create a separate vector drawing.  If you want to save as a vector, why not [create as a vector](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-map-element.html#svg-0)?

Comment: Since I'm considering building a quick logo creation app, there would only be the options to import from a library of SVG files, and then fonts of course.  Along with a few basic editing features (like color, gradient, size, etc..) everything still would be vector, or at least coming from a vector source.

Comment: @GarySimon Everything will be a vector until you place it in `canvas`, if you want it to stay vector don't take that step.

Comment: Ah okay thanks.  I would assume then the interface in which the visitor works with would be less than ideal when you compare it with the Canvas ability to easily work with objects.

Comment: @GarySimon Canvas has no ability to work with objects, everything you draw on a `canvas` ends up as pixels, it retains no knowledge or information about the drawing commands that put the pixels there.  It is with SVG where you are working with objects.